# Updating a lookup field from a Silverlight app - CRM 2011

Tags: c#, javascript, silverlight, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm using the following code to try and update a lookup field value in my CRM 2011 system from a silverlight app:

```
try
{
    ma.my_ActionDetails = details;

    Guid userId = new Guid();
    foreach (SystemUser s in SystemUsers)
    {
        if (s.FullName.Equals(comboBox1.SelectedItem))
        {
            userId = s.SystemUserId;
        }
    }

    // Define eval statements for setting lookup to a value and null
    string setLookupJscript = @"Xrm.Page.getAttribute(""{0}"").setValue([ {{ id: ""{1:B}"", typename: ""{2}"", name: ""{3}"" }}])";
    string evalStatement = null;

    // Set the statement to be evaluated based upon the value of the id argument
    // Setting the lookup to a value 
    evalStatement = string.Format(setLookupJscript, "my_salesperson", userId, "my_memberaction", ma.my_SalesPerson.Name);

    HtmlPage.Window.Eval(evalStatement);

    _context.UpdateObject(ma);
    _context.BeginSaveChanges(OnUpdateAccountComplete, ma);
}
catch (SystemException se)
{
    _syncContext.Send(new SendOrPostCallback(showErrorDetails), se);
}
```

However when I run this code it generates the following errors:

In the browser:

```
'Xrm' is undefined
```

From the code:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: [Common_MethodFailed]
```

Can anyone explain whats going on here?

Thanks,

Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be within the context of a CRM form for the Xrm namespace to be available. Are you running from within a form?

From the [CRM SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328358.aspx):

> If your Silverlight web resource is designed to be viewed in an entity form, the form has an Xrm.Page.context object you can use to access contextual information.
>
> If you need your Silverlight application to appear outside the context of the form you must configure an HTML web resource to provide this context information by adding a reference to the ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx page. After this reference is added, your Silverlight application can access contextual information in the same way it can in an entity form. The following sample shows how to call the getServerUrl function from the Xrm.Page.context object.

```
private string serverUrl = "";
ScriptObject xrm = (ScriptObject)HtmlPage.Window.GetProperty("Xrm");
ScriptObject page = (ScriptObject)xrm.GetProperty("Page");
ScriptObject pageContext = (ScriptObject)page.GetProperty("context");
serverUrl = (string)pageContext.Invoke("getServerUrl");
```